# Adding two Y axes to an xy plot

Tags: r, series, lattice

Working with this [data](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/Card1995.Rdata) in Rstudio. I need to run a simple regression of `ed76` on `lwage76` and a saturated regression that turns `ed76` into a dummy variable for every level within the column. Then I need to plot both regressions in an XY plot with `lwage76` as the Y axis and `ed76` as the X axis. This is what I have so far:

```
regression <- lm(nlsdata$lwage76~nlsdata$ed76)

predicted <- data.frame(Edu =nlsdata$ed76, Wage = predict(regression))

aggplot <- aggregate(Wage ~ Edu, data=predicted, mean)
xyplot( Wage ~ Edu, data = aggplot, grid = TRUE, type = c("p","l"))
```

This gives me a very nice XY plot, but now I need to add the predicted values from my staturated model:

```
satreg <- lm(lwage76 ~ ed76*edu_1 + ed76*edu_2 + ed76*edu_3 + 
             ed76*edu_4 + ed76*edu_5 + ed76*edu_6 + ed76*edu_7 + 
             ed76*edu_8 + ed76*edu_9 + ed76*edu_10 + ed76*edu_11 +
             ed76*edu_12 + ed76*edu_13 + ed76*edu_14 + ed76*edu_15 + 
             ed76*edu_16 + ed76*edu_17, data = nlsdata)

satmodel <- data.frame(Edu =nlsdata$ed76, Wage = predict(satreg))
```

So how do I add the second data set to the graph that I have?

Comment: That's not "adding a second y-axis", it's only plotting a second series. Both series share the same one y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in ggplot:

```
ggplot(data=predicted, aes(Edu, Wage)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=satmodel, colour="blue") +
  geom_point(data=satmodel, colour="blue")
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can label each of your table and combined them into a single data.frame.

```
satmodel <- satmodel %>% mutate(type="sat_model")
predicted <- predicted %>% mutate(type="predicted")

df <- rbind(satmodel, predicted)


ggplot(df, aes(Edu, Wage, colour=type)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: do I need a special package to run the second code block of code that you provided? When I run it I get a `could not find function "%>%"` error.

Comment: @MichaelPerdue yup. I usually load package `dplyr` by default. Sorry for not clarifying earlier.